# mrjob ssh configuration error

Tags: python, ssh, emr, mrjob

I am new to mrjob and trying to run the basic word count script from mrjob document. I could run it successfully on emr by setting ssh false(ssh_tunnel_to_job_tracker: false). However, if I changed the option to true and run the script, I kept having the error.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\MyIpython>python word_count.py -r emr 111.txt
using configs in C:\Users\Administrator\.mrjob.conf
creating new scratch bucket mrjob-5dd9c3ac4aa59e82
using s3://mrjob-5dd9c3ac4aa59e82/tmp/ as our scratch dir on S3
creating tmp directory c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\word_count.Administr
ator.20150729.080450.654000
writing master bootstrap script to c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\word_cou
nt.Administrator.20150729.080450.654000\b.py

PLEASE NOTE: Starting in mrjob v0.5.0, protocols will be strict by default. It's
 recommended you run your job with --strict-protocols or set up mrjob.conf as de
scribed at https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/whats-new.html#ready-for-strict-protoc
ols

creating S3 bucket 'mrjob-5dd9c3ac4aa59e82' to use as scratch space
Copying non-input files into s3://mrjob-5dd9c3ac4aa59e82/tmp/word_count.Administ
rator.20150729.080450.654000/files/
Waiting 5.0s for S3 eventual consistency
Creating Elastic MapReduce job flow
Job flow created with ID: j-B3GUOBAWHZ29
Created new job flow j-B3GUOBAWHZ29
Job launched 35.3s ago, status STARTING: Provisioning Amazon EC2 capacity
Job launched 69.0s ago, status STARTING: Provisioning Amazon EC2 capacity
Job launched 103.2s ago, status STARTING: Provisioning Amazon EC2 capacity
Job launched 139.3s ago, status STARTING: Provisioning Amazon EC2 capacity
Job launched 184.7s ago, status STARTING: Provisioning Amazon EC2 capacity
Job launched 219.1s ago, status BOOTSTRAPPING: Running bootstrap actions
Job launched 253.4s ago, status BOOTSTRAPPING: Running bootstrap actions
Job launched 287.3s ago, status BOOTSTRAPPING: Running bootstrap actions
Job launched 323.1s ago, status BOOTSTRAPPING: Running bootstrap actions
Job launched 356.6s ago, status RUNNING: Running step (word_count.Administrator.
20150729.080450.654000: Step 1 of 1)
Opening ssh tunnel to Hadoop job tracker
Attempting to terminate job...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word_count.py", line 16, in <module>
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\job.py", line 461, in
run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\job.py", line 479, in
execute
    super(MRJob, self).execute()
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\launch.py", line 153,
in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\launch.py", line 221,
in run_job
    self.stdout.flush()
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\runner.py", line 633,
in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\emr.py", line 1146, in
 cleanup
    super(EMRJobRunner, self).cleanup(mode=mode)
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\runner.py", line 577,
in cleanup
    self._cleanup_job()
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\emr.py", line 1218, in
 _cleanup_job
    self._opts['ec2_key_pair_file'])
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\ssh.py", line 197, in
ssh_terminate_single_job
    ssh_bin, address, ec2_key_pair_file, ['hadoop', 'job', '-list']))
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mrjob\ssh.py", line 82, in s
sh_run
    p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "F:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_chil
d
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2]
```

This is what my config file look like:

```
runners:   
  emr:
    aws_access_key_id: xxx
    aws_secret_access_key: xxx
    aws_region: us-east-1
    ec2_key_pair: EMR
    ec2_key_pair_file: C:\Users\Administrator\EMR.pem
    ssh_tunnel_to_job_tracker: true
```

The location of pem file should be correct. I do not know where is the problem.

Comment: Hi Matin, I think this is a question regarding python programming and should be on-topic according to the definition [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I've misunderstood your question.